# Bootstrap 3 btn does not wrap the second line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implemented a button just like the one demontrated in [the example page of fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/), whose code is:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x pull-left"></i> Font Awesome<br>
  Version 4.3.0
</a>
```

It works but only when the second line is no more longer than the first one.

So what causes the weird phenomenon and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Edit:

There is a running demo over [here](http://104.236.211.26).

This is a single page app and the broken btns is over the second scene.

Comment: What code have you tried? Please provide your html and css so we can help

Comment: Do you mind writing some custom CSS to fix this issue?

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://www.bootply.com/L3OZZkDE6b (Tested with and without spaces, your code and code from Font Awesome Documentation)

Comment: I have add the link to the demo. Sorry for my latency.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes with `white-space: nowrap;`. Bootstrap sets it on `.btn`. In most cases the text in buttons is on one line. In your case it must be on two. So, add a custom class to the button and overwrite it, like this:

```
.btn-custom {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: It do make the btn wrap the word but is not what I expect.

Comment: The result is over [here](http://satellite:2333/), you may compare it with the linked page in my question. Is there better solution?